# Primary Secondary server in Weblogic

Tags: session, weblogic, load-balancing

I have apache proxy web server ahead of 6 weblogic instances which are part of a single cluster.

For a client that hits my application the Apache's access logs shows the below loggin

```
/Replica/AddServlet;jsessionid=PvqTQtYfKLrzBHtT1dpcJX5WhryRgpTGBvMJ8pLbpJnSDR5p0K65!1647512983!-1661904304!1357731903334 HTTP/1.1" 200 284
```

How can I determine which out the six is the primary and which is the secondary weblogic server for this client request ?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (a data mining technique known as "clustering"), but oviously you meant [tag:load-balancing]. Do check you are using the tags that you meant to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to switch on the Apache DEBUG log, which notes the individual server HASH and maps it to the Managed server.

Turn on proxy debug by setting `Debug=”ALL”` in the proxy configuration file.

Example configuration for Apache plug-in (httpd.conf):

```
<Location /mywebapp>
 SetHandlerweblogic-handler
 WebLogicCluster sol1:8001,sol2:8001,sol3:8003
 Debug ALL
 DebugConfigInfo ON
 WLLogFile /tmp/wlproxy.log
 </Location>
```

You can then see the exact host:port for your primary and secondary for the request.

Example from http://www.bea-weblogic.com/weblogic-server-support-pattern-common-diagnostic-process-for-proxy-plug-in-problems.html

Or try this link

http://www.findsol.com/blog/weblogic-server-support-pattern-common-diagnostic-process-for-proxy-plug-in-problems/

```
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 getpreferredServersFromCookie: -2032354160!-457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 GET Primary JVMID1: -2032354160
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 GET Secondary JVMID2: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 [Found Primary]: 172.18.137.50:38625:65535
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 list[0].jvmid: -2032354160
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 secondary str: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 list[1].jvmid: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 secondary str: -457294087
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 [Found Secondary]: 172.18.137.54:38625:65535
Mon May 10 13:14:40 2004 Found 2 servers
```

Remember each time you restart the weblogic servers, new HASHes are used.

Comment: The webpage http://www.bea-weblogic.com/weblogic-server-support-pattern-common-diagnostic-process-for-proxy-plug-in-problems.html is not working. Can you share the details ?

Comment: http://www.findsol.com/blog/weblogic-server-support-pattern-common-diagnostic-process-for-proxy-plug-in-problems/

Comment: Below are my settings. <IfModule mod_weblogic.c> WebLogicCluster 10.10.102.171:6001,10.10.102.171:8080,10.10.102.47:8081 MatchExpression /MyApp </IfModule> <Location /weblogic> Debug ALL DebugConfigInfo ON WebLogicCluster 10.10.102.171:6001,10.10.102.171:8080,10.10.102.47:8081 PathTrim /MyApp </Location> but it does not show any logging. I am also not able to see any wlproxy.log in my windows. Where and how I can get this information?

Comment: you havent specified `WLLogFile` locatin

Comment: Why does the default[c:\TEMP\wlproxy.log] not work for me ? I have windows 7

Comment: I tried to hit my application from three different IP addresses however, The string "Found Primary" and "Found Secondary" which apprears three times each in the WLLogFile; remains the same[unchanged i.e same IP:Posrts] for all the three hits. Can you explain why ? I want to ceck all 6 servers as primary and see what is the secondary match for all the six conditions.

Comment: Also, i see three entries for Found cookie from cookie header: JSESSIONID=QqlHQntQ7qsFd9sjDw4bbsp3jkMVKWpTYpKTz0JHpZ2PMVY1VvR2!-796990916!-1561295513 when I was expecting new cookies for each of the 3 hits.